# Install Undermount Sink as a Drop-In

Tags: kitchen-sink

I recently purchased a sink (at a great price) only to find out it's an under mount model (see link below).  Can I install this as a drop-in?  Was thinking the laminate counter would not be supportive enough.  Can I router the edges for a flat fit for drop-in?

https://www.mrdirectint.com/848-mocha-large-single-bowl-undermount-trugranite-kitchen-sink.html

Comment: I don't think so. Drop-in sinks actually have a gasket between them and the countertop, and a little bump to give room for the gasket.

Comment: Above or below mount doesn't make a difference in counter strength. Can you install it in a way the sink is not advertised? Of course! Will it work in the long run? Maybe, maybe not... Why don't you ask the sink manufacturer customer service if it can be done or is advisable.

Comment: The "lip" of the undermount sink could be rough, sharp, or otherwise "unfinished" because it was never designed to be seen or touched.  You really won't know that until you see it in person.

Comment: I bought a house that had an undermount cast iron sink installed as a drop-in. As other comments point out, the outer edge may well not be finished well since it wasn't intended to be visible, and also the underside of the flange may not be that flat, depending on the molding method used, so seating and sealing on the top of the counter may be challenging. Both were the case with my sink. If you're prepared to put in some effort in case you find that with your, you could probably make it work. Mine had no way to use the clamps to hold it to the counter, it relied on the caulk - which worked.